What would be the best recommendation for a tool summarize books using the ToC?
That is it, I'm looking for a tool that helps me summarize each chapter/section of a book independently (with some context of the previous chapters as you would have if you were reading it). Initially I would like to start by reading pdf files.
So far, I've looked at ollama-ebook-summary, but it seems more of an experiment than a settled tool.
Ideally, I would like to execute everything locally.
